# How to manage DbContext in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

At very first, every time when I use `GYOSContext`, I just create a new instance to do the CRUD operations. Since some of my data model is not simple, I always met an exception of

```
EF：An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

I guess the problem is caused because there are multiple `DbContext` instances working on the same data model. So I try to store `DbContext` in the session, each time for manager class will get the same instane of `DbContext`, which solve my problem perfectly.

The question is that I'm not quite sure if it is good solution or not. Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Code at first :

```
public class GYOSContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Code improved :

```
 public class GYOSContext : DbContext
{
    private GYOSContext()
    {

    }

    public static GYOSContext GetGyosContext()
    {
        var db = HttpContext.Current.Session["GYOSContext"] as GYOSContext;
        if (db == null)
        {
            db = new GYOSContext();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["GYOSContext"] = db;
        }
        return db;
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm worried what if there are thousands user online at the same time, there will be 1000 instances of Context.

Comment: Show the code that throws the exception. Having many context instances is not a problem, the problem is how to move your entities from one context to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never wise to store your context in session.

Each controller action should create an instance of GYOSContext, and dispose of that instance once the action completes.

The pattern should be something like

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    using (GYOSContext context = new GYOSContext())
    {
        // Do stuff with context

    }  // Automatically disposed when exiting scope of using block
}
```

Comment: Because context is widely used, and sometimes there're more than one instance of context working on the same data model. which caused Exception. I'm trying to manage context to ensure every time there's only one instance works to avoid the exception.

Comment: There should only be one instance of Context *for a given HTTP request* if you follow the pattern above.  You get into trouble if you try to use a Context beyond the scope of a single HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

it is not a good practice to manage DbContext by storing at session level, application level or by using single tone pattern, i will go with creating the context at controller level like the sample below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private DbContext db;

    public HomeController(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Do stuff with context
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```